# How can I allow updating database tables through csv import into a temporary table?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm setting up a postgreSQL database for a company to help them sort out a mess of Excel files with duplicated data, too many versions, etc.

The company has generally inexperienced users who would balk at the command line interface. I'm providing them with enough queries to be able to get their work done and I will write more as needed. They expect they could become proficient enough with PGAdmin 4.

One of the major tasks will be to update data in persistent tables and they would be most comfortable updating Excel files, converting them to CSV and running a query. I want to allow them to do that by uploading the data into a temporary table using the COPY command and then using INSERT / UPDATE commands with conditions to not overwrite/duplicate existing rows using the WHERE clause.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to have them do everything they need to from PGAdmin 4, and I'm stuck on the part where they can upload a CSV file and update the tables from that. A sample query is shown below.

The only solution I've found seems to be executing /copy from the command line interface, which I'm trying to avoid.

AWS RDS does not allow granting superuser privileges from the master account I've created. Nor can I grant the pg_read_server_files role to anyone.

They would first load the file into a temp_table:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (
    col1 TEXT,
    col2 TEXT,
    col3 TEXT,
    col4 TEXT,
    col5 TEXT
);

COPY temp_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) FROM 'file_path' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Once the data is loaded into the temp_table, they will execute:

```sql
INSERT INTO persistent_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
FROM temp_table 
WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM persistent_table);
```

The first bit of code gives me this error.

> ERROR:  must be superuser or a member of the pg_read_server_files role to COPY from a file
>   HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
>   SQL state: 42501

Comment: If they are happy using excel files why are they using a database, excel has sharing options now. ?

Comment: Well, they're not too happy with Excel files because it doesn't prevent adding duplicate entries, there's a bit of joining to do with the various tables, there are many versions of the Excel files floating around.

Comment: You can import to a table using pgAdmin4 from a file. Then create a procedure that can be called to update the main table when called using the ON CONFLICT clause. Or schedule the update to run overnight with cron or pg_agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pgAdmin4 has its own feature similar to psql's \copy to load data from a client-side file.  After you right click on a table name, it offers the import/export dialog.  Just like \copy, this uses COPY...FROM STDIN behind the scenes.  You can think of it as a GUI equivalent to \copy, which seems to be just what you are asking for.

Comment: Ah, you've saved the project. Thank you so much.